# How to Read Multiple Inputs separated by a space from one input line?

Tags: c#, input

Let's say I have a program that asks for the Full Name:

```
string firstName;
string surName;

Console.Write("Enter your full name:");
```

let's say the user inputs the string "Santa Clause"

if I use:

```
firstName = Console.ReadLine();
```

"Santa Clause" will be stored to firstName, but I only want the "Santa" part.

Is there a way to read only the first word when two or more words are separated by a space? Is there also a way to read the other words (like "Clause")?

Comment: one way to do it is using the [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to read only the first word when two or more words are
>   separated by a space?

You can use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method.

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified Unicode character array.

Like;

```
string firstName = "Santa Clause";
string[] splitedNames = firstName.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(splitedNames[0]);
```

Output will be;

```
Santa
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/oaqr3W).

> Is there also a way to read the other words (like "Clause")?

Sure, since `String.Split` return a string array, you can find the other words using the index number of array like `splitedNames[1]`, `splitedNames[2]`, etc..

Answer (score 2):

try `Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')` which will give you `string[]`

Answer (score 2):

Use the string.Split() method:

```
var fullName = Console.ReadLine()
firstName = fullName.Split(' ')[0];
surName = fullName.Split(' ')[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

The [**String.Split Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) is your friend here:

```
string full = "Santa Clause";
string[] parts = full.Split(' ');
string first = parts[0];
string last = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fullName = Console.ReadLine();
fullName = fullName.Split(' ')[0];

var firstName = fullName[0];
var surName = fullname[1];
```

This is assuming the user enters correct input such as "Santa Clause" otherwise the application will fall over.